# Extract all subnets from its first common octet

Tags: linux, awk, grep, ip-address

I have a list of subnets  in a file. I just need to extract those subnets which have  common octet as mentioned.

I tried using grep "grep -oP '1.[^"]+' but still I got some different results.

for example I have a log as.

```
1.1.1.0/24
2.74.2.0/24
11.2.1.0/24
1.9.55.0/24
```

I just want to extract the subnet having common first octect as 1 so the result should be

```
1.1.1.0/24
1.9.55.0/24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
grep '^1\.' filename
```

The `^` symbol indicates the beginning of the line, and `\.` means literal dot.

Answer (score 1):

Print each line where the first dot-separated field is 1:

```
awk -F. '$1=="1" {print}' datafile
```

Since each line of an `awk` script is `condition {action}`, and either part can be omitted for a default `1 {print}`, the line can be written more fluently as this:

```
awk -F. '$1=="1"' datafile
```